# grails: can the @Secured be applied on a domain class annotated with @Resource?

Tags: grails, spring-security

When using `@Resource` on a domain class to implement a RESTful controller, can one further annotate the Domain class with `@Secured`, and expect security to be affected on the resulting controller?

I.E.:

```
@Resource
@Secured(['ROLE_MEMBER'])
class Book {
    String name
}
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently supported but feel free to add a feature request at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE/